# Get tweets of user with python

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm trying to build a python script that will record all of a user's tweets (up to 3200) to a file.  What's the best way to go about this?  I've tried Tweepy and Twython, but can't figure out how to get all (or up to 3200) of a user's tweets.

Comment: Try google or provide a bit of code...Here's something to get you started though...http://blogs.fluidinfo.com/terry/2009/06/24/python-code-for-retrieving-all-your-tweets/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might not be the answer you're looking for, but if you just want a particular user's tweets, you could try just utilizing twitter's api: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/user_timeline

You'll just need to know how to handle the request and the response.

You can do so rather simply with: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/ and the standard XML and JSON libraries provided in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`statuses/user_timeline`](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/user_timeline) Twitter API with a [Twitter Python bindings library](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/twitter-libraries#python).